# Flutter integration tests for iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, firebase-test-lab, flutter-integration-test

I have followed documentation from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test#ios-device-testing to set up Flutter integration tests for iOS on Firebase Test Lab. However I’m stuck and get various errors when running the tests locally with the command when trying to run the command `xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun ...`

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace temporary with scheme Transient Testing.
        Reason: Cannot test target "RunnerTests" on "iPhone 12 Pro Max": Unable to determine the executable path for Runner.app
```

Does anybody  know how to fix this error and to get Flutter integration tests for iOS running? Thanks in advance!

Comment: any progress? im also curious about this, we're even trying device farm

Comment: @nAndroid I have filed an issue on GitHub, please comment on it to show that this is an urgent problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82701
Firebase Test Lab and Android works fine however.